# Insert rows where there are missing values

Tags: r, dataframe

Data is like:

```
 quarter name  week  value
 17Q3    abc   1     0.7
 17Q3    abc   3     0.65
 17Q3    def   1     0.13
 17Q3    def   2     0.04
```

Can I insert rows with value=0 where there is missing values for week i.e the output should be like:

```
quarter name  week  value
 17Q3    abc   1     0.7
 17Q3    abc   3     0.65
 17Q3    abc   2     0.0
 17Q3    def   1     0.13
 17Q3    def   2     0.04
 17Q3    def   3     0.0
```

need to fill till week 13.(i.e check till 13)

Comment: Try `library(dplyr);df1 %>% complete(quarter, name, week = full_seq(week, 1), fill = list(value = 0)) %>% arrange(quarter, name, id) %>% mutate(id = row_number()) %>% select(names(df1))`

Comment: Thanks..i have tried with library(dplyr);df1 %>% complete(quarter, name, week = full_seq(week, 1), fill = list(value = 0))  ..got the error like couldnt find the function complete

Comment: `complete` is from `tidyr`  sorry

Comment: Thanks alot..it did the wonder.solved.

Comment: actually i dont have id column.and i am getting repetitive rows after the codes mentioned above. library(tidyr);df1 %>% complete(quarter, name, week = full_seq(week, 1), fill = list(value = 0)) .

Comment: You showed the 'id' column in the example

Comment: sorry..my bad.i mistaken the data.but now i checked,there is no id column

Answer (score 1):

How about by using `expand` within `complete`.

```
library(tidyverse)
complete(df, expand(df, quarter, name, week), fill = list(value=0))

#   quarter name   week  value
#   <fct>   <fct> <int>  <dbl>
# 1 17Q3    abc       1 0.700 
# 2 17Q3    abc       2 0     
# 3 17Q3    abc       3 0.650 
# 4 17Q3    def       1 0.130 
# 5 17Q3    def       2 0.0400
# 6 17Q3    def       3 0
```

Or, maybe easier to understand:

```
df %>% expand(quarter, name, week) %>% left_join(df) %>% replace_na(list(value=0))
```

Comment: this will give repeated results

Comment: add `%>% distinct()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`.  We get the missing combination of rows with `complete`, `arrange` the rows based on the 'quarter', 'name' and 'id', then `mutate` the 'id' to 'row_number())`and`select` the columns to have the same order as in the original dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
  complete(quarter, name, week = full_seq(week, 1), fill = list(value = 0)) %>%
  arrange(quarter, name, id) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  select(names(df1))
# A tibble: 6 x 5
#     id quarter name   week  value
#  <int> <chr>   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1     1 17Q3    abc    1.00 0.700 
#2     2 17Q3    abc    3.00 0.650 
#3     3 17Q3    abc    2.00 0     
#4     4 17Q3    def    1.00 0.130 
#5     5 17Q3    def    2.00 0.0400
#6     6 17Q3    def    3.00 0
```

Comment: Thanks Akrun..Is there a way if we dont have id column. I am getting repetitive rows.One way is to remove duplicates.

Comment: another updates.i need to fill till week 13. adding full_seq(week,1,13) didnt help.

Comment: @buntysahoo  Please update your input data and expected output in the post

Comment: updated the post itself.. i need to check till week 13 and fill till 13.

Comment: solved...have used unique function and it gave exact solution.Thanks a lot Akrun.